# Checking to see if a value exists in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I prevent a Javascript alert from firing if the alert value is undefined?  In other words, something like this:

```
if (alert(message) != 'undefined') {
        alert(message);
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/typeof):

```
if (typeof message !== 'undefined')
```

Don't put `alert(message)` into the `if` expression, otherwise you will *execute* `alert` (which we want to avoid before we know the type of `message`) and the return value (which is also `undefined` btw ;)) will be compared to `undefined`.

**Update** Clarification for `!==`:

This operator not only compares the value of two operands but also the **type**. That means no [*type coercion*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion) is done:

```
42 == "42" // true
42 === "42" // false
```

In this case it is not really necessary because we know that `typeof` always returns a string but it is good practice and if you use it thoroughly and consistently, it is more clear where you really want to have type coercion and where not.

Comment: Note how Felix used the !== operator instead of !=. Douglas Crockford explains this (and other awesome JS facts) here: http://video.yahoo.com/watch/630959/2974197